# What happens if I use a 240v clothes iron in USA?

Tags: electrical-engineering

Since all it really is is a heating element, what happens if I use a 240v/50Hz clothes iron with a 110v/60Hz supply?

Comment: Be careful: if it's a fancy-schmancy iron with tilt sensors, auto-timeout, etc., you might make the low-voltage electronics unhappy.

Comment: You might, although if it is fancy-schmancy, it is very likely the low voltage power supply is done right and will do its job both for 110V and for 230V...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, anything with a heating element will produce only 1/4 the heat on 1/2 the voltage, since power is proportional to voltage squared.

In other words, you'll probably be disappointed with the results.

Comment: `P = IV` so why the 1/4 to 1/2 ratio?

Comment: With a constant resistance, when you halve the voltage, you also halve the current.

Comment: @SteveLorimer - It's `P = V^2/R` variant in this case, not `P = VI`

Comment: @GlenH7 Both formulae apply. One is more obvious than the other. Also P = I^2 x R. With half voltage you also get half current as I = V/R. Plugging in both I & V figures as approriate gives the same results with all 3 formulae.